# How do I stop this attack on my wordpress site?

Tags: database, wordpress, web, hosting, brute-force

My wordpress webstore which is hosted on hostinger is being attacked intermittently and is going down and up. I received an email prior to the attack asking me to send money to a bitcoin address or the site will remain under attack. I didn't respond and am trying to fix this.

When I try to access my website, I get the following error:

"Error establishing a database connection"

So, then I went into Hostinger and tried to connect to phpmyadmin which connects for a few seconds and displays this error:

" mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1226): User 'u223395032_vYqof' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 50)"

I've ensured I have a firewall running on my wordpress site through a wordpress plugin, and also have the option to prevent brute force attacks enabled. What else can I do here to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a slowloris attack. Which means you have an issue in managing your connection limit within your code or your server. Firewall can't block that because it's aa legitimate connection to your application. It is your code block that treat the connection that should be modified. To prevent that from happening again :

- Increase *max_user_connections* on your MySQL configuration ( it will not resolve the issue, but better try
- Chose a connection release after every query ( connection.release(); )
- Using a cache plugin that enables client side cache is your biggest defense of all.
- Use Wordfence free plugin as a firewall. This will detect the attackers IP address and block it after ( for example ) 10 consecutive connections.
- After you get it done, attack your own website to verify if it can handle external attacks ( Example on linux : nmap --script http-slowloris --max-parallelism 400 [your_website] -vv ). Use this one carefully.

You can see the following article, it will help you : https://www.storminternet.co.uk/blog/Slowloris-outbreak-affecting-newly-updated-WordPress-sites/318